# Did The Rebbe R' Heshel of Krokow have a different version of the Chumash?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, text, pinchas

In the Sefer Chanukas Hatorah, [written by the Rebbe R' Heshel of Krocow], in Parshas Pinchas (Bamidbar 27:3) it says:

> בפסוק (במדבר כז:ג) - אבינו מת במדבר **והוא לא היה בתוך העדה הנועדים על
>   ה' בעדת קרח ובנים לא היו לו כי בחטאו מת** וגו'.
>
> In the pasuk (Bamidbar 27:3) - "Our father died in the wilderness,
>   **and he was not among the company of them that gathered themselves together against HaShem in the company of Korah, and he had no sons,
>   but he died in his own sin**;"
>
> ויש לדקדק **דהוה ליה למיכתב כי בחטאו מת תיכף אחר הדיבור והוא לא היה
>   בעדת קרח**,
>
> It should be noted, that the pasuk should have written "**but he died
>   in his own sin**;"immediately after saying "**and he was not among the
>   company...of Korah**".
>
> וכך הוה ליה למיכתב **אבינו מת במדבר והוא לא היה בתוך הנועדים על ה'
>   בעדת קרח כי בחטאו מת ובנים לא היו לו**
>
> And this is how it should have been written:
>
> "**'Our father died in the wilderness, and he was not among the
>   company of them that gathered themselves together against HaShem in
>   the company of Korah, but he died in his own sin; and he had no
>   sons**".

PROBLEM: In the standard version of the Torah, The pasuk quoted, reads:

**אָבִינוּ מֵת בַּמִּדְבָּר וְהוּא לֹא הָיָה בְּתוֹךְ הָעֵדָה הַנּוֹעָדִים עַל ה' בַּעֲדַת קֹרַח כִּֽי בְחֶטְאוֹ מֵת וּבָנִים לֹא הָיוּ לֽוֹ**׃

"**Our father died in the wilderness, and he was not among the company of them that gathered themselves together against HaShem in the company of Korah, but he died in his own sin; and he had no sons**".

**The way he quotes the Pasuk is not the way it is written in our version of the Torah**. On the contrary, the way he says "*It should have been written*" is **exactly the way the pasuk is indeed written**.

The question is obvious: **Did The Rebbe R' Heshel of Krakow have a different version of the Chumash?**

Comment: Note that in some cases authors wrote books without having access to sources, either because books were expensive or not available, or for some special circumstances. For instance R Shlomo Teichtal wrote Eim HaBanim Semeicha while hiding from the nazis y"s" and without access to books. He quotes from a wide range of sources, all from memory. Publishers later on had to correct many quotes who were nearly but not perfectly correct. Maybe this partly explains the issue here as well

Answer (score 3):

Various suggestions have been put forward in a number of forum pages, see [here](http://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=14090), [here](https://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=35262), [here](http://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=3661&hilit=%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%AA+%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94) [here](http://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=19074) and [here](https://www.tora-forum.co.il/viewtopic.php?style=9&t=1358).

In short:

Yeshevav Hasofer notes that not everything in the Sefer is from Rav Heschel himself, but rather that the publisher added things in from other sources:

> בהיותי במתיבתא שמעתי על כך ממגי"ש שלי.
>   למעשה לפני כשנתיים שמעתי דיבת רבים, שהמדפיס של חנוכת התורה וקול אליהו, רבי חנוך העניך ערזאהן ז"ל, שילב לתוך הספרים כמה דברים מספרים אחרים שהם בסגנון דומה לחידושי הגר"א והרבי רבי העשל, ושמעתי שיש בספרו קטע שלם שהוצא כצורתו מסה"ק עבודת ישראל להמגיד מקוזניץ זצ"ל, וכן שמעתי שאף הכניס מפרי רעיוניו שרצה לתלות באילני רברבי, ויש ללמד זכות שדבר זה הוא מאלו ששירבב המדפיס לתוך הספר ל'השביח' מקחו, וזה טעות שלו ולא של הרבי רבי העשל זצ"ל.

Shimen adds that the source of this particular "vort" is elsewhere (apparently [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42564&st=%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%97&pgnum=54)), although without the question.  He therefore suggests that this was an addition by the publisher/collector, who added in the question in order to strengthen the vort, except that when it was added, it was added without consulting a Chumash:

> עכשיו מצאתי שבמקור הדברים בלקט שמואל נכד הסמ"ע נמצא הווארט אבל רק התירוץ בלי הקושיא אלא שהמלקט הוסיף הקושיא כדינ להטעים הדבר כמ"ש בהקדמה לחנוכת התורה שדרך הלקט שמואל לקצר ולכן היה צריך לבאר דבריו, וכאן טעה כי לא היה החומש מונח לפניו באותה שעה.

If you are interested to see what textual variants there may be in manuscripts of this verse, consider [asking on Biblical Hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: There's another mistake - in the כך הוה ליה למכתב he's missing the word העדה.  This lends credence to whoever added this being a little sloppy.